# MarshalJSON a String Declared Type

Tags: go

I have created a new declared type and added a method to marshal the value into JSON

```
type TextOutput string

func (t *TextOutput) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`{"data": "%s"}`, t)), nil
}
```

When I try to marshal an instance of the type I get the raw value returned. What am I missing?

```
var t TextOutput
t = `Test test`
output, err := json.Marshal(t)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
} else {
    fmt.Println(string(output))
}
// prints Test Test. Expected {"data": "Test test"}
```

Comment: Where is your `UnmarshalJSON` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem stems from how interfaces in Go are implicitly satisfied.
In this particular case, the `json.Marshal` method uses type assertion at runtime to see if the given value implements `json.Marshaler`. Effective Go [mentions this very case](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#blank_implements).

You could have satisfied the `json.Marshaler` for the `*TextOutput` type using a pointer-receiver like so:

```
func (t *TextOutput) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`{"data":"%s"}`, *t)), nil
}
```

And for this to work properly, pass the reference to the `json.Marshal` function:

```
var t TextOutput
t = `Test test`
output, err := json.Marshal(&t)
```

However, implementing it using a value-receiver ensures that both `TextOutput` and `*TextOutput` types implement `json.Marshaler`

```
func (t TextOutput) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`{"data": "%s"}`, t)), nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the `MarshalJSON` interface as a non-pointer.

```
func (t TextOutput) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`{"data": "%s"}`, t)), nil
}
```

Play Link: https://play.golang.org/p/lLK6zsAkOi

Output:

```
{"data":"Test test"}
```